# Show Message if results are empty

Tags: angularjs, forms, ionic-framework

I have a search form for products. I would like to make sure that it shows me a message when the list is empty, when there is no result.

My code :

```
<form ng-controller="productCtrl" name="searchForm" ng-submit="searchProduct()" ng-disabled="searchForm.$invalid">
    <input placeholder="Search" type="text" ng-model="form.name" required>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="product in list track by $index">{{ product.name }}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **ng-if** above the **ng-repeat**

Like this

```
<div ng-if="list.length<=0" style="color:red;">Error!</div>
```

**Ex:**

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <div ng-if="todos.length<=0" style="color:red;">Error!</div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in todos">{{item.color}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vqJ5q/48/

Answer (score 0):

There's many different answers, like :

1. Use *ng-if** or *ng-show* in another element that show empty state message. Check length of list that will shown. If `list.length <= 0` show this error.
2. Add condition too with *ng-if* or *ng-hide* in *ng-if* element. If `list.length <=0`.
3. Or you can create Boolean flag in your scope Object, like *isShowEmptyState=false* and just set `true` when list was empty